# Table layout changes after dialog

Tags: layout, dialog, sapui5

I have a page with 2 sap.ui.table.Tables on. If I open a dialog on that page the layout of my tables changes making the separators between the header cells not align with the separators between the row cells.

My dialog also contains a sap.ui.table.Table

How do I prevent this from happening? Or how can I fix this?

Comment: I have had this exact same problem, and I ended up resizing the columns programmatically as a workaround (setting width to a different value and then to the previous value again everytime the dialog was opened). I won't post that as an answer because it is really not a proper solution ( `col.setWidth(x+1); col.setWidth(x) `). I think, however, that your question could be improved with some example code, so everyone can see what you mean: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could invalidate the Table (leading to a re-render) after the Dialog closes.

This will give Table a chance to get it's headers and cells back in sync.

Something like this:

```
new sap.m.Dialog({
    afterClose: function() {
        oTable.invalidate();
    }
});
```